# Issues importing python-pptx on Linux (Ubuntu 17)

Tags: python, linux, python-pptx

I am trying to import the python pptx library in a python programm. I installed it using pip before, which gave me the following output:

```
Collecting python-pptx
Downloading python-pptx-0.6.6.tar.gz (8.4MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.4MB 132kB/s 
Collecting Pillow>=2.6.1 (from python-pptx)
Downloading Pillow-4.2.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.8MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.8MB 193kB/s 
Collecting XlsxWriter>=0.5.7 (from python-pptx)
Downloading XlsxWriter-0.9.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (137kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting lxml>=3.1.0 (from python-pptx)
Downloading lxml-3.8.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.8MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.8MB 166kB/s 
Collecting olefile (from Pillow>=2.6.1->python-pptx)
Downloading olefile-0.44.zip (74kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 1.3MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: python-pptx, olefile
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-pptx ... done
Stored in directory: /home/clemens/.cache/pip/wheels/27/f8     /dc/181ed5439001413ee0c1c8794a06009c4c0b96f652401e2d20
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for olefile ... done
Stored in directory: /home/clemens/.cache/pip/wheels/20/58 /49/cc7bd00345397059149a10b0259ef38b867935ea2ecff99a9b
Successfully built python-pptx olefile
Installing collected packages: olefile, Pillow, XlsxWriter, lxml, python-pptx
Successfully installed Pillow-4.2.1 XlsxWriter-0.9.8 lxml-3.8.0 olefile-0.44 python-pptx-0.6.6
```

So this seems to be a success. 
But as I am trying to import the module using the following code:

```
try:
    from pptx import Presentation
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

It says `No module named 'pptx'`.
It must have something to do with Linux since the same code works just fine on windows and the module seems to be installed correctly. I am using Python 3.5.3.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Anaconda? If so, make sure that you're using the correct python executable

Comment: @bendl I am using the original python interpreter

Comment: Using pip install, you'll install it for Python2, not for python3.
To make sure it gets installed for Python3, invoke pip from the interpreter, like this:
 python3 -m pip install <package>

Comment: @Kavli thank you! that worked.

Comment: @Kavli This is a good answer, I recommend you provide it as an answer (and C.Dautermann that you accept it) so others can find it more easily when they arrive here on search. I'm sure others will face the same problem and they might move on without a close look if they don't see an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pip install, you'll install it for Python2, not for Python3. To make sure it gets installed for Python3, invoke pip from the interpreter, like this:

```
python3 -m pip install <package>
```